# REST HATEOS: How to remove dependency on fixed URL?

Tags: rest, hateoas

We are creating product search page. We have around 50k stocks i.e. e-commerce website has.

To get first page stocks, the clients get data through following API:

/api/stocks/?pn=1

In response, the server sends back:

1. The array of stocks of page number 1
2. The next page url i.e. /api/stocks/?pn=2

HATEOS suggest "A REST client enters a REST application through a simple fixed URL."

But i feel it is being violated as we are hard-coding first api url on every client i.e. each client will hard-code this url "/api/stocks/?pn=1" for first page load.

Is there any way to avoid this hard-coding?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing is, you could create the following url:

```
/api/stocks
```

That would simply redirect to the first page. This way users would not have to hard-code specific parameters that you might change in the future.

The second steps might be, if you have more functionality offered through your API is to create a *landing page*. This is basically what an "index" page is for human readers, just for machines:

```
/api
```

This would return only links to `/api/stocks` and other parts of your API.

Comment: but client have budget dropdowns, so in case user fills budget they will have to pass: /api/stocks/?budget=1-3 and this would bring hard-coding at the client side. How avoid this?

Comment: I see. If the client *selects/inputs* things, you have to provide all the options from the server side (to avoid hardcoded options). That means the client first has to request a "page", and on that page you describe what the client's options are and how to submit it. Take a look at this thing for ideas: https://github.com/vanillasource/gerec/wiki/Forms

Comment: I didn't get this link. Can you suggest some other link? I want to remove all API hard-coding from the clients. Is it possible?